# What flower is it and why it has leaves only

Tags: identification, flowers, planting

I bought the bulbs in Costco 1.5 mo ago and forgot the name. What is it?

[image]

It looks tall and big leaves but no flower so far now in July timeframe. I am in Pacific Northwest.

Is it a goner?

Answer (score 3):

No need to worry.

That’s a [tuberous begonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia_%C3%97_tuberhybrida) - and it’s just too small to flower yet. Unlike the spring bulbs you may be more familiar with, these begonias have tubers that can go dormant (what you bought) and regrow again in spring and will flower when they are grown into good-sized plants.

Take good care of it and expect flowers in a few weeks.